# How to loop through an array using for loop in react native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over json data in react native.I want to create a new array with different `key` and `values` will be the looped json result.I've tried the following but nothing is working as expected.The format of json response will be the following.

**json**

```
 0: {key: 0, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A1. India's Economic Development", duration: 0, …}
    1: {key: 1, id: "1", type: "unit", title: "1. India as a Developing Economy", duration: 0, …}
    2: {key: 2, id: "2", type: "unit", title: "2. Understanding India’s economic transition", duration: 0, …}
    3: {key: 17, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A2. National Income", duration: 0, …}
    4: {key: 18, id: "5", type: "unit", title: "1. India in the global economy", duration: 0, …}
    5: {key: 19, id: "6", type: "unit", title: "2. China, India and the rise of Asia", duration: 0, …}
```

I want an array like this

```
const dataArray = [
  {
    title: "India's Economic Development",
    content:
      "India as a Developing Economy",
      "Understanding India’s economic transition"

  },
  {
    title: "National Income",
    content:
      "India in the global economy",
      "China, India and the rise of Asia"
  }
]
```

Following is the looping I've done but nothing is coming.Please help

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {

    responseData.map(detail => {

        let resultk = [];
        //console.log( detail.data.curriculum);
        for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < detail.data.curriculum.length; i++) {
            curr = detail.data.curriculum;
            console.log(curr.title);
            if (curr.type === "section") {
                resultk['title'] = curr.title;
                this.result[j++] = resultk;

            } else if (curr.type === "unit") {
                resultk['content'] = curr.title;
            }
        }
        console.log(resultk)
    })
})
```

Comment: define resultk as `let resultk={} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` function and a variable to track the index of the accumulator array

Check it type is section then in the accumulator array push the value and update the variable value by 1.

If the type is unit then add the value in the content which is at the index defined by `currIndex` variable

```js
let value = [{
    key: 0,
    id: 0,
    type: "section",
    title: "A1. India's Economic Development",
    duration: 0
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    id: "1",
    type: "unit",
    title: "1. India as a Developing Economy",
    duration: 0
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    id: "2",
    type: "unit",
    title: "2. Understanding India’s economic transition",
    duration: 0
  },
  {
    key: 17,
    id: 0,
    type: "section",
    title: "A2. National Income",
    duration: 0
  },
  {
    key: 18,
    id: "5",
    type: "unit",
    title: "1. India in the global economy",
    duration: 0
  },
  {
    key: 19,
    id: "6",
    type: "unit",
    title: "2. China, India and the rise of Asia",
    duration: 0
  }
]

let currIndex = -1;
let k = value.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  if (curr.type === 'section') {
    acc.push({
      title: curr.title.split('.')[1].trim(),
      content: []
    })
    currIndex += 1
  } else {
    acc[currIndex].content.push(curr.title)
  }

  return acc;


}, []);
console.log(k)
```

Comment: I tried your code and I found that it is more efficient than the other.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
const resp = [
    {key: 0, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A1. India's Economic Development", duration: 0},
    {key: 1, id: "1", type: "unit", title: "1. India as a Developing Economy", duration: 0},
    {key: 2, id: "2", type: "unit", title: "2. Understanding India’s economic transition", duration: 0},
    {key: 17, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A2. National Income", duration: 0},
    {key: 18, id: "5", type: "unit", title: "1. India in the global economy", duration: 0},
    {key: 19, id: "6", type: "unit", title: "2. China, India and the rise of Asia", duration: 0},
]
```

If resp is an object with a length and 0, 1, 2, ... keys, use Array.from(obj) to convert it to an object

If the resp is sorted (each unit belongs to the previous section)

```
const result = []
resp.forEach(item => {
    if (item.type === 'section') { // create a new collection
        result.push({
            title: item.title,
            content: []
        })
    } else if (item.type === 'unit') {
        if (result.length === 0) throw new Error('No section specified yet')
        result[result.length - 1].content.push(item.title)
    } else {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid data type')
    }
})
```

To trim the first word from the title use

```
function removeFirstWord(str) {
    return str.replace(/^[^\s]+\s/, '')
}
```

The /symbols/ thing is called regular expression

- The string starts with (first ^ sign) any character expect a
- whitespace (whitespace=\s, [^something] means **not** something)
- the plus sign means the last part can repeat 1 or more times

so far it finds the first word

- the \s means also replace the space after the word

Comment: How do I list the content array?.I want to map over that

Comment: If its not an array, but something like this:
{
  0: object,
  1: object,
  2: object,
  length: 3,
}

Use `Array.from(arrayLike)` to convert it to an array

If that what you ask for

Or if you are asking how do I access the results, its the `result` array, use it after my script

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example code of what you want, try changing your data with the final loop and you will get your desire output :

```
testingggg = () => {
    var data = {
        0: {key: 0, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A1. India's Economic Development", duration: 0},
        1: {key: 1, id: "1", type: "unit", title: "1. India as a Developing Economy", duration: 0},
        2: {key: 2, id: "2", type: "unit", title: "2. Understanding India’s economic transition", duration: 0},
        3: {key: 17, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A2. National Income", duration: 0},
        4: {key: 18, id: "5", type: "unit", title: "1. India in the global economy", duration: 0},
        5: {key: 19, id: "6", type: "unit", title: "2. China, India and the rise of Asia", duration: 0}
    }

    var keys = [];
    for(var k in data) keys.push(k);

    //alert("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys);

    var dataArray = [] 

    for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
    {
        var newObj = { // Change your required detail here
            type: data[i].type,
            title: data[i].title
        }
        dataArray.push(newObj);
    }
    console.log(dataArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution. If I understand the question correctly you want to reformat and combine the section as the title and the unit(s) as the content...

```
var data = {
    0: { key: 0, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A1. India's Economic Development", duration: 0 },
    1: { key: 1, id: "1", type: "unit", title: "1. India as a Developing Economy", duration: 0 },
    2: { key: 2, id: "2", type: "unit", title: "2. Understanding India’s economic transition", duration: 0 },
    3: { key: 17, id: 0, type: "section", title: "A2. National Income", duration: 0 },
    4: { key: 18, id: "5", type: "unit", title: "1. India in the global economy", duration: 0 },
    5: { key: 19, id: "6", type: "unit", title: "2. China, India and the rise of Asia", duration: 0 }
};

var keys = Object.keys(data);

var dataArray = [];
var push = true;
var toPush = null;

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

    var key = keys[i];
    var obj = data[key];

    switch (obj.type) {
        case "section":
            if (toPush !== null) {
                dataArray.push({ ...toPush });
            }
            toPush = {};
            var titleText = obj.title.split(".")[1].trim();//if there is always a "." in the title string this will clean that up;
            toPush.title ? toPush.title += `, ${titleText}` : toPush.title = titleText;
            push = true;
            break;
        case "unit":
            push = false;
            var contentText = obj.title.split(".")[1].trim();//if there is always a "." in the title string this will clean that up;
            toPush.content ? toPush.content += `, ${contentText}` : toPush.content = contentText;
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}

//push the last one
dataArray.push({ ...toPush });

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray, null, 2));

//result =>
[
  {
    "title": "India's Economic Development",
    "content": "India as a Developing Economy, Understanding India’s economic transition"
  },
  {
    "title": "National Income",
    "content": "India in the global economy, China, India and the rise of Asia"
  }
]
```